# Why is LLDB sometimes showing me my source assembly and sometimes not?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, lldb

I've been working through x86-64 some assembly examples under macosx (Monterey 12.5).  To generate an executable I've been using:

```
% as -g -o tallest.o tallest.s
% ld -static -o tallest tallest.o
```

Up to now, I've been able to step through the code and LLDB shows me file and line number as well as the source code with current line highlighted as I step through the code.  For example:

```
Process 52754 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000fc9 tallest`start at tallest.s:41
   38       leaq people(%rip), %rbx
   39  
   40       # record count in %rcx
-> 41       movq numpeople(%rip), %rcx
   42  
   43       # tallest yet found in %rdi
   44       movq $0, %rdi
Target 0: (tallest) stopped.
```

But sometimes, in this same debugging session, I get this:

```
(lldb) n
Process 52754 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000fd0 tallest`start + 14
tallest`start:
->  0x100000fd0 <+14>: movq   $0x0, %rdi
    0x100000fd7 <+21>: cmpq   $0x0, %rcx
    0x100000fdb <+25>: je     0x100000ff7               ; finish

tallest`mainloop:
    0x100000fe1 <+0>:  movq   0x18(%rbx), %rax
Target 0: (tallest) stopped.
```

LLDB is not showing me the file contents.  After a few more steps we are back to normal:

```
(lldb) n
Process 52754 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = instruction step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000fe1 tallest`mainloop at tallest.s:54
   51       # %rbx holds base address of people array
   52       # move value of current person height into %rax
   53       # movq HEIGHT_OFFSET(%rbx), %rdx
-> 54       movq HEIGHT_OFFSET(%rbx), %rax
   55  
   56       # compare to tallest yet found
   57       cmpq %rax, %rdi
Target 0: (tallest) stopped.
```

It is always the same lines that it can or cannot show.  There is only one file (tallest.s).  It is hand written assembly.

Why is LLDB only sometimes able to figure out the right part of my source file to display?

Is there something I can do to ensure that it can always show me the related source, when I hit a break-point?

Comment: What commands did you use to build your `.s` into an executable?  Like `clang -g tallest.s`?  A debugger needs debug metadata to map addresses to/from line numbers.

Comment: I assembled the .s file with `as -g -o tallest.o tallest.s`, then I linked it with `ld -static -o tallest tallest.o`.

Comment: Take a look at the line table for your .s file (use lldb's `source info -f tallest.s` to dump this).  This is the mapping from addresses to source lines that lldb uses to show you source.  Then look for the address entries where you weren't seeing line number information.  Either they will be missing or they will have a line number of 0.  If the former, that's likely a compiler bug, it isn't giving line number info for some addresses.  If the latter, that's a case where the compiler has to emit some code but there isn't a good line number to attribute it to.

Comment: The latter case is also inconvenient, but sometimes it's more confusing to be told "this code is from line 10" when it clearly isn't than "we don't know what line this code is attributed to."

Comment: @JimIngham The lines are missing from src info.  The compiler in this case is actually an llvm assembler.

Comment: Is HEIGHT_OFFSET a macro?  Macro expansion can do funny things in the line table.

Comment: @JimIngham HEIGHT_OFFSET is a symbol established with the .equ instruction. eg `.equ HEIGHT_OFFSET, 0x18`

Comment: That's unlikely to be it then...  Anyway, getting line table information right is not entirely trivial and definitely has had and will continue to have bugs & need work.  I would also guess (though I don't work on this stuff) that less time is spent on line table quality for the assembler than for the compiler.  So if you want to make progress here, you will need to file some bugs.  If you are using the `as` that lives in Xcode, that comes from the llvm project so either Apple's bug reporter or the llvm.org bug tracker would be appropriate places to start.